# Sudden error with regex compiling in reworked script

Tags: regex, python-3.x

So, this question is not really about the error (sre_constants.error: look-behind requires fixed-width pattern), I know what that error means. My problem ist that this function:

```
import regex as re

def _sent_split(phrase):
    abbreviations = r'Mr|Dr|Sr|Mrs|Sra|Dra|Av|D|Da|Gob|Gral|Ing|Prof|Profa|Srta'
    sentence_endings = r'\.|!|\?|—|»|«'
    sentence_starters = r'\p{Lu}|¿|¡|-|»|"| |*|—|«'

    splitPattern = r'(?<!\([^\)]*?(?=(?<=(?<!'+abbreviations+')['+sentence_endings+']"?)[ |\n](?=['+sentence_starters+'])[^\(\)]*\)))(?<=(?<!'+abbreviations+')['+sentence_endings+']"?)[ |\n](?=['+sentence_starters+'])'
    splitPattern2 = r'(?<=:"?)[ |\n]'

    pattern = re.compile(splitPattern+"|"+splitPattern2)

    phraseList = re.split(pattern, phrase)

    return phraseList
```

is throwing that error. I was reworking a bigger script and this is a part of it. The thing is, that I changed nothing in that function. The parameter phrase is still the same input (a part of a text as a string). But suddenly it doesn't want to compile anymore and throws that error.

Do you have any idea what might be wrong? If i test this function independently, it also works, it only doesn't work in the script which is super weird, as it's independet from the rest.

Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: What error? What is the input string? I have just compiled it, no issues. Well, your patterns are a bit not fine, but I have not encountered any compile issues. `sentence_starters = r'\p{Lu}|¿|¡|-|»|"| |*|—|«'` must be re-written as `sentence_starters = r'\p{Lu}¿¡»" *—«-'`. And sentence endings - `sentence_endings = r'.!?—»«'`. You are using them inside `[...]`, so no need to escape and the `-` must be at the start/end.

Comment: That doesn't sound like an error the `regex` module would throw. Are you _sure_ you've correctly imported `regex as re`? What's the output of `print(re)`?

Comment: Try on https://regex101.com/r/rbYZZx/1 to see the error.

Comment: @Tiger-222: `regex` pattern can be tested at a .NET regex tester, not regex101. The resulting pattern is valid. See http://refiddle.com/refiddles/594ba5da75622d19c9218d00.

Comment: @Rawing Thanks, your tip was correct. It used the standard re module instead of regex, which caused the error.

Comment: @IP Then you did not have `import regex as re` in your code. The code you posted is correct and does not produce any errors.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I did have it, which is the weird thing. To make it work, I only deleted the "as re" part and changed all "re" to "regex". Btw thanks for your tips for improvment in regards to my pattern, always happy to learn something. :-)